React UI elements linked to 3D spatial positions inside WebGL/Unity
I'm working on an application involving a Unity viewer using WebGL embedded in my React App, and I'm thinking of the best approach to embed some 3D elements fixed to some spatial locations on the 3D space inside the Unity viewer but display them on an overlay made in React, above the Unity app. This has the benefit of separation of concerns of the UI elements from the Unity WebGL renderer to the UI framework (React) but I don't feel this will be performant since React doesn't always perform state updates immediately and likes to batch and trigger state updates all at once when lots of state changes occur (which will happen as the state of the position of the UI element on the overlay will change every time the camera moves), which will give it a jittery and laggy experience.
I'm aware of how to do this in native three js and html, where we can update the element's position on the overlay/canvas inside the render or loop function which is usually called inside the requestAnimationsFrame function to achieve high frame rates, but I don't think it will be feasible or recommended to modify exterior UI elements from Unity as it will again be the quite the opposite of separation of concerns. but even in that approach, if updating the element's position, isn't it a DOM operation and aren't DOM operations very expensive? and doing them at every render? like 60 times a second, is it ideal?
With this, I can also think of using a canvas instead of a usual overlay and add the html elements or draw them on the canvas maybe? I'm still unsure of the exact implementation, I'm just trying to clarify the complete high level design for it. I believe drawing on the canvas would be less expensive than DOM updates and also more real time than React's state updates? But that would also mean there will be two canvases, one for the custom elements' and the other used by Unity. I will have to selectively disable pointer events on the top canvas (for the custom elements) but enable pointer events on the custom elements on it? am I thinking in the right direction?
